# Empty space at page end for last anchor

Tags: javascript, html, css

We have a page with a list of anchors. Content for each anchor shows on top of the window once navigations are clicked.

However for the last anchor, the content won't go to the top of the page because there isn't enough content at the end of the page. Hence empty space has to be added, this creates a problem for different sizes of windows.

Is there anyway to solve the problem without the empty space?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

You can use [`:target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/En/CSS/%3atarget) pseudoclass to style anchored element corresponding to hash part of URL, thus making anchored element more noticeable for user.

Also, some websites has footer with huge (with tons of copyrights, disclaimers, archive links, etc.) height that makes it possible for page to be scrolled even to anchors that are at the end of content area.

Answer (score 1):

No...if the page isn't long enough, clicking a named anchor will merely bring it into the viewport. Without a ton of padding, it won't pop the element to the top of the page.

Instead of adding a bunch of padding to the bottom of the page, you could use some kind of visual cue to draw the user's eye to the selected element after clicking it.